# Conversion - 'Result' is not a member of 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient, vb.net-to-c#

Using VS 2010, VB.NET, HTTPClient, .NET 4.0, and Windows Forms.

I am trying to get a windows application to consume JSON coming from a Web API that I have created.  Web API works great and I can view the results from a browser.  Found this article that I have been trying to get working only using VB.NET instead of C#.
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-wpf-application

The critical part of the code is this function:

```
private void GetProducts(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
btnGetProducts.IsEnabled = false;

client.GetAsync("api/products/2").ContinueWith((t) =>
{
    if (t.IsFaulted)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(t.Exception.Message);
        btnGetProducts.IsEnabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        var response = t.Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Product>>().
                ContinueWith(t2 =>
                    {
                        if (t2.IsFaulted)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(t2.Exception.Message);
                            btnGetProducts.IsEnabled = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var products = t2.Result;
                            _products.CopyFrom(products);
                            btnGetProducts.IsEnabled = true;
                        }
                    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }

    }
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

I have tried to convert this to VB.NET but I am having issues with the t.Result saying "'Result' is not a member of 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'."

Here is my attempt to convert it to VB.NET:

```
Private Sub GetProducts(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    btnGetProducts.IsEnabled = False

    client.GetAsync("api/products/2") _
        .ContinueWith(Of HttpResponseMessage) _
        (Function(t)
             If t.IsFaulted Then
                 MessageBox.Show(t.Exception.Message)
                 btnGetProducts.IsEnabled = True
             Else

                 '***************************************************************
                 Dim response = t.Result 'This is the line that is giving me grief. Error Msg: 'Result' is not a member of 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'.
                 '***************************************************************

                 If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                     response.Content.ReadAsAsync(Of IEnumerable(Of SendNotice)).ContinueWith _
                         (Function(t2)
                              If t2.IsFaulted Then
                                  MessageBox.Show(t2.Exception.Message)
                                  btnGetProducts.IsEnabled = True
                              Else
                                  Dim products = t2.Result
                                  _lstSN.CopyFrom(products)
                                  btnGetProducts.IsEnabled = True
                              End If

                          End Function, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())

                 End If
             End If

         End Function, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
End Sub
```

Any idea why I am getting this error and what am I missing in my code to allow me to catch the returning JSON data?

Thanks!

Comment: You're converting from/to the wrong language :-)

Comment: I so agree! But that is what everyone else is using in the department.

Comment: I have a feeling you're missing an extension method. Are all your imports correct?

Comment: lol! Yes, I am trying to convert it to VB.NET and not to C#.

Comment: These are the imports that I am using and showing up as correct. Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Net.Http.Headers
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Comment: You should almost NEVER call task.result. It is a great way to implement deadlocks.

Comment: It looks like it thinks its `Task` not `Task<T>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because VB.NET type inference is not great in Visual Studio 2010. You'll need to give the compiler a bit of extra help by specifying the *actual* type returned by your `client.GetAsync()`, like so:

```
client _
   .GetAsync("api/products/2") _
   .ContinueWith( _
       Sub(t As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage))
           ...
       End Sub, _
       TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
```

*Note: I've changed your Function to Sub because I didn't see any Return statements.*

Comment: You ROCK! Thank you and to everyone else who have tried to help!

Comment: @user3019291, glad to help. You'll find that type inference works a lot better in VS2012/2013, but for now keep this workaround in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
client.GetAsync("api/products/2") _
        .ContinueWith(Sub(t)
                       If t.IsFaulted Then
                       .
                       .
                       .
```

Comment: I have done this and I am still having the same issue as before. 'Result' is not a member of 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'.  The t.IsFaulted seems to be okay. Intellisense even shows that t.Result should work.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your lambda from a Function to a Sub.